# filebeat JSON logging broken logs in Elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch, logging, logstash, filebeat

I'm using filebeat>kafka>logstash>elastiserach stack of version 7.15.0.
My logs are getting broken and not writing properly into elastic which is resulting in json.erros

```
error.message:Key 'log' not found 
error.type: json
```

and

```
error.message:Error decoding JSON: invalid character 's' after array element error.type:json
```

my log contains both json and nonjson contents
my docker stdout logs>>

```
{"log":"{\"instant\":{\"epochSecond\":1643023707,\"nanoOfSecond\":538281000},\"thread\":\"grpc-default-executor-11\",\"level\":\"INFO\",\"loggerName\":\"com.abc.ab.ab.core.service.integration.controller.NotifyCoreGrpcController\",\"message\":\"RMQ_CORE_GRPC_NOTIFY RESP : {\\\"baseBizResponse\\\":{\\\"success\\\":true,\\\"resultCode\\\":\\\"SUCCESS\\\"}} \",\"endOfBatch\":false,\"loggerFqcn\":\"org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLogger\",\"contextMap\":{\"RMQ_ID\":\"2022012401445669241212121212\",\"FLOW_TYPE\":\"RMQ_CORE_GRPC_NOTIFY\",\"MERCHANT_TRANS_ID\":\"bcd4ab1e54abaha122\",\"spanId\":\"4fa1474c078afceb\",\"traceId\":\"bcd4ab1e54abaha122\"},\"threadId\":100,\"threadPriority\":5,\"dateTime\":\"2022-01-24T16:58:27.538+0530\"}\r\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2022-01-24T11:28:27.538354156Z"}
```

and

```
[244540.169s][debug][gc,age] GC(51) Desired survivor size 80740352 bytes, new threshold 15 (max threshold 15)
```

Filebeat conf>>

```
filebeat.yml: |
      filebeat.inputs:
      - type: container
        multiline.pattern: ^[[:space:]]'
        multiline.negate: false
        multiline.match: after
        json.keys_under_root: true
        json.message_key: log
        json.add_error_key: true
        enabled: true
        paths:
          - /var/log/containers/*.log
        exclude_files: ['fluentd-*', 'istio-*', 'cluster-logging-*', 'infra-*']
        processors:
          - add_kubernetes_metadata: 
              in_cluster: true
              host: ${NODE_NAME}
              default_matchers.enabled: false
              matchers:
              - logs_path:
                  logs_path: "/var/log/containers/"
      processors:
        - drop_fields:
            fields:
              - 'kubernetes.node.name'
      output.kafka:
         enabled: true
         hosts: ["kafka1:9092","kafka2:9092","kafka3:9092"]
         partition.round_robin:
           reachable_only: false
         required_acks: 1
         compression: gzip
         max_message_bytes: 10000000
         topics:
         - topic: '%{[kubernetes.labels.app]}'
           default: 'app-perf-k8s-logs'

      filebeat.config.modules:
        path: ${path.config}/modules.d/*.yml
      filebeat.modules:
      - module: nginx
      - module: kafka
      logging.level: debug
```

logstash config >>

```
input {
  kafka { 
    topics_pattern => ".*."
    bootstrap_servers => "kafka1:9092","kafka2:9092","kafka3:9092"
    client_id => "logstash"
    codec => json 
    decorate_events => true
    consumer_threads => 10
    heartbeat_interval_ms => "100000"
    session_timeout_ms => "300000"
    poll_timeout_ms => 300000
    partition_assignment_strategy => "org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.RoundRobinAssignor"
    request_timeout_ms => "400000"
    group_id => "logConsumer" 
    auto_offset_reset => "latest"
  } 
}

output {
 
 elasticsearch {
                    hosts => "es-logging-perf-lb.abc.com:80"
                    index => "filebeat-%{[@metadata][kafka][topic]}-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
}
```

Please help and suggest.

Comment: Seems self explanatory... You've set `json.message_key: log`... Meanwhile, at least one of your events has `Key 'log' not found`. If your log contains non-json data, then setting json properties for parsing probably isn't a good idea, and you'll get messages like `Error decoding JSON: invalid character`. Try **not** parsing json in Filebeat, and instead use logstash `filter` to match and parse the data, while changing the codec back to plaintext

Comment: @OneCricketeer I used this 
grok {
    match => {
      "message" => [
        "{%{GREEDYDATA:json_message}}",
        "%{GREEDYDATA:std_out}"
     ]
  }
}
if [json_message]
{
    mutate {
        replace => { "json_message" => "{%{json_message}}"}
    }
    json {
        source => "json_message"
        target => "log"
     }
}
but It's not working.
Can you please share snippet for this ?

Comment: Can you clarify "isn't working"? It'd be easier if you shared `stdout { codec => rubydebug }` output that gets generated from that

Comment: Also, if the data is already in Kafka, it may be easier to use [Kafka Connect](https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-elasticsearch-connector-tutorial/)

Comment: Please [edit] the question to inclide those additional details

Comment: @OneCricketeer
I used this for now 
filter {
 json { source =>"message"
        target => "log"
   }
  }
and it's working but there are 2 issue.
1. field name append with log ex- loggerName > log.loggerName, dateTime> log.dateTime
2. error.message:Error decoding JSON: invalid character 's' after array element 
still there.

Comment: You're embedding data within a `log` JSON object like `{"log": {"loggerName": "test"}}`, so you get dot-notation when written... Then, you have extra data that is not-JSON, as explained. For example, `[244540.169s][debug][gc,age]` has an "s" after "an array element" in the timestamp